# What does those yellow exclamation marks mean in my solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

[image]

I clone a git repo and create dotnet core web API on that repo. I'm using visual studio 2017 and when I did a code modification and saved the yellow exclamation mark will be displayed. How can I remove those?

Comment: It means that the file is part of your Project but it's actually missing from Disk

Comment: @JamieRees But those controller files are there. and I Can even open it using Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Yellow triangle generally indicates a warning in VS. Since warnings are displayed on class (.cs) files, the meaning is that those files are a part of the solution, but are not present on your disk.
My best guess is that reclonning / syncing your local repo with master should resolve your issue.

Comment: even I push the changes with `git push`. the mark will be not disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by updating the VS 2017 to the latest by Visual Studio Installer.